# How to find merge conflicted files author

Tags: git

I use below commands to merge `develop` into `release` branch and to find conflicted files author/devloper.

```
1) git clone repository
2) git checkout release
3) git merge --no-commit develop
4) git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
5) git log file-name
```

1. Is there a way to find conflicted files between branch without running merge command?
2. How do I find each conflicted file's responsible developer for multiple files at once?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is the right way: `merge --no-commit`. That way you can look around without actually performing the merge. `git status` will tell you instantly where the problems are.

The concept of a "conflicted file's responsible developer" makes no sense to me so I'm not answering that part.

Keep in mind that merge conflicts are *normal*. They are not a problem or a sign of wrongdoing. They are a totally benign byproduct of collaboration.

Comment: `git status` gives the list of conflicted files. Further to work collaboratively with concern developer to resolve merge conflicts, I'm looking for a way to get the developer name for each conflicted file. Since in our case we have many conflicted files.

Comment: As I already said, the concept "developer name for conflicted file" doesn't mean anything to me so I didn't discuss that in my answer. Files don't have developers.